# Real world location for the Dursleys' house?

Tags: harry-potter, real-location

Is there a real place that the Dursleys' address was based on? We know in-world that they lived at 4 Privet Drive in Little Whinging, Surrey. Does Rowling ever let us know if there was a real world street she based their neighborhood on, if it's not an actual real place?

[image: Still of "Privet Drive" from film]

Comment: Is phantom42 correct in his assessment of your question, or is my answer valid? (see comments on my answer)

Comment: @randal'thor im looking for both technicly though he is right that its unclear

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### In-universe, it's probably somewhere near Staines.

[image: location]

[This article](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/atlas/britain/atlas-b-surrey.html) in the HP Lexicon gives a very good argument for Little Whinging (the location of the Dursleys' house) being roughly where it's shown on this map, in the far north of Surrey close to Staines.

---

### It was filmed in Martins Heron, Berkshire.

The [filming location](http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryMagazine/DestinationsUK/harry-potter-film-locations/), meanwhile, is No. 12, Picket Post Close, in the village of Martins Heron near Bracknell in Berkshire. Here's a screenshot from Google Street View, so you can see it's the same:

[image: street]

Comment: Oh god, it's near Staines.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question asked. I read it as asking for what real life area the location is based off of. This is more about where it would be in real life.

Comment: @phantom42 OP says he's looking for both (see comments on question).

Comment: Don't forget that I think as early as the second film (definitely early on) they built the exterior of the house and at least one other to make filming easier.

Comment: Just as a side note there is only 12 miles between Staines Upon Thames and Bracknell, geographically they are quite similar.

Answer (score 15):

[JK Rowlings thoughts](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Number_Four,_Privet_Drive_%28location%29)

> Although I describe the Dursleys' house as big and square, as befitted Uncle Vernon's status as a company director, whenever I wrote about it I was unconsciously visualising the second house I lived in as a child, which on the contrary was a rather small three-bedroomed house in the suburb of Winterbourne, near Bristol.

Comment: You may also be interested to know that Winterbourne is home to a Dragon Road, Green Dragon Road and a pub called the George and Dragon and the Potter surname originated from some of JK's friends in the village (according to wikipedia).