# How long does it take Hedwig to bring a letter to Ron or Hermione?

Tags: harry-potter

I can't answer this question because I know that Harry lives in Surrey, but I don't know where Hermione or Ron live? Do you know?

And even if you do not know, do you have any idea how much time Hedwig takes to bring a letter?

Comment: Hedwig, like most space vessels, flies at the speed of plot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Most likely within mere hours.

---

While we do not know exactly where either Ron or Hermione live [we have actually no idea at all about Hermione], nor where in Surrey *Little Whinging* is supposed to be, we *do* know a couple of things:

- Hagrid drops Harry of at Paddington for his return to Little Whinging after the shopping trip on his 11th birthday. *[PS]*
- ***Errol*** managed to get Molly's Howler from *The Burrow* to *Hogwarts* between Dumbledore writing her and Arthur about the boys arriving by car (which he could have done after the feast he had to
  return to at the earliest) until breakfast the next day. Meaning a
  school owl had to deliver Dumbledore's letter, Molly had to write
  down her answer and then had to send her old bird across the country.    *[CoS]*
- *The Burrow* can not be too far from London, because Muggle taxi drivers where willing to drive 9 (all the Weasleys except Arthur and Percy plus Harry and Hermione) people to *King's Cross*. I don't know how this works in the UK, but I expect that they could not be long distance trips (because otherwise either taking the Knight Bus or flooing to the Leaky Cauldron and taking the Tube to the train station would have been cheaper and much quicker). *[GoF]*
- *The Burrow* is somewhere to the west of Little Whinging, but not too far west (the Wiki states *Ottery St. Catchpole* is in Devon but gives no proof [but based on the guess that it might be near the River Otter in Devon]), meaning either to the south west or the north west of Surrey:

> You’re driving too far west, Fred,” [George] added, pointing at a compass on the dashboard. Fred twiddled the steering wheel. *[CoS]*

- *Hogwarts* is in the Scottish Highlands.

> At this point, it became a matter of urgency to find some more discreet method of transporting hundreds of wizarding children from all over Britain to their secret school in the Highlands of Scotland. *[JKR on Pottermore "The Hogwarts Express"](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express)*

- [Bird of Prey Flight Top speeds in the Real world](http://www.rodentpro.com/birds-of-prey-flight-speeds-north-america.asp) - it is uncertain if those are the same in the magical world. Pigwidgeon - when he did not yet have a name - was able to keep up with the Hogwarts Express for at least a bit, so maybe magical owls are faster.

  `Barn Owl         50 mph
  Snowy Owl        50 mph
  Great Horned Owl 40 mph
  Short-eared Owl  26 mph`

**Conclusion:** If **Errol** of all owls can get a letter overnight from most likely Devon to the Highlands of Scotland, **Hedwig** will be quicker to deliver a letter from *Privet Drive* to either *The Burrow* or almost anywhere else on the island, so wherever Hermione may live it would most likely be nearer to Surrey than Hogwarts. In fact, the answer of a letter from Harry to either of them should reach him within hours.

Comment: While it is not required by the question it would be interesting also to learn what might have been the average speed of an owl, both considering it simply flies the whole way without stops and also with some biology checking , regarding how far owls usually can fly without rest.

Comment: @Gnudiff A agree, but all I have is my Harry Potter books, and owl speed - apart from the fact that the as of then not yet named Pig managed to keep level with the Hogwarts Express at least long enough for Harry to snatch him up in *PoA* - is not mentioned (with the possible exception that tiny owls should be used for local deliveries only) in them, I couldn't say anything about that.  But I found some info and will add it now---

Comment: I don’t see how we can say that The Burrow is west of Little Whinging. The fact that Fred is driving too far west doesn’t really tell us anything much, except that they weren’t going due east at the time. The Burrow could be in Kent for all we know; if they were going in a generally southward direction at the time, Fred might have been going too far west according to the direction they were supposed to go. I would definitely consider a taxi trip from Devon to London to be quite long.

Comment: The Burrow is in Ottery St Catchpole, Devon... it's written on Pottermore (https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/the-burrow)

Comment: And of course, there are other instances of owls which arrive much faster. In _CoS_, the Ministry owl notifying Harry of ‘his’ crime (Dobby’s Hover charm) doesn’t seem to take more than perhaps half an hour or so to get there, and in _OotP_ the Ministry owl prematurely expelling Harry seems to be there in no more than perhaps 10–15 minutes from Harry’s Patronus (and that includes the time used in detecting the spell, deciding on a course of action, and writing the letter).

Comment: @brt22 Cool. Like I said the Potter wiki says Devon as well, but - to me at least - there is *Pottermore* and *Written-by-JKR-Pottermore*. The first is the staff there inventing stuff (that hopefully does not contradict existing canon), the second is word-of-god.  But Devon is a fairly good guess, since the River Otter is located there, as well as the real village of Ottery St. Mary.

Comment: The distance between Devon and Surrey is about 250 km, so if Hedwig's speed is 80 km/h it takes just over 3 hours to bring a letter from Privet Drive to the Burrow. This is very approximate but I am satisfied that in the end we have an answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Like I said, magical owls might be even faster. Depending where in Surrey the owl needs to go it's not necessarily that far from the Ministry.  In OotP, Umbridge staged the Dementor attack, therefore she might have everything already in place to send the letter out - it's fairly late in the evening (around dusk) on a summer day (so around 8-9pm maybe?)... I dunno about British civil servants, but at least here in Germany any public office would be long closed by that time.

Comment: @BMWurm You’d expect so, wouldn’t you? I doubt Umbridge has everything staged, though: the letter is signed by Mafalda Hopkirk (as was the letter in _CoS_), and Umbridge never told anyone she was the one who sent the Dementors. I think owl speed is a somewhat inconsistently described _deus ex machina_, similar to the Fidelius Charm. On the one hand, there are the almost immediate ones from the Ministry; on the other, there are the letters from Sirius while he’s in hiding, which take several weeks to arrive. It doesn’t seem like Rowling has given much thought to owl speed overall.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, unfortunately that seems the way.

Comment: Is there nothing in FBAWTFT about owl speeds?

Comment: Regarding the first sentence after your tl;dr: not only do we know where Ron lives (as pointed out by @brt22), we also know [where the Dursleys live](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107451/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Cool. Didn't know that... although, like the Weasleys living in Devon, it is also just guesswork. Probably a good guess though...

Comment: @Edlothiad I wish... there isn't anything about owls at all in there ... neither in the 2001 nor the 2017 edition. The only thing under *O* is the *Occamy*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Essentially owls travel with the speed of plot - (**Warning TV-Tropes!** https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot

Answer (score 7):

### There is contradictory evidence

In the beginning of *Goblet of Fire* there is owl correspondence between Harry and Ron.

> Harry — DAD GOT THE TICKETS — Ireland versus  Bulgaria, Monday night.
>   Mum’s writing to the Muggles  to ask you to stay. They might already
>   have the letter,
>
> I don’t know how fast Muggle post is. Thought I’d send  this with Pig
>   anyway.

We see here that Ron is not sure whether owl post or Muggle post is faster. It is clear that he did not write his letter *after* his mother did, and presumably he sent the letter when he finished writing it, but it is possible that his mother didn't mail the letter right away. Even assuming that both letters were sent at approximately the same time, they arrived at Harry's house at about the same time as well so it would appear that owl post is just as slow as Muggle post.

However, Harry responds right back to Ron:

> Harry seized his eagle-feather quill once more,  grabbed a fresh piece
>   of parchment, and wrote:
>
> Ron, it’s all okay, the Muggles say I can come. See you five o’clock
>   tomorrow. Can’t wait.
>
> Harry

This appears to assume that Hedwig would be able to deliver the letter in one day, which is probably faster than Muggle post.

We also know that Hedwig is pretty fast because in the beginning of *Prisoner of Azkaban* she got to the Leaky Caulldron only five minutes after Harry did via the Knight Bus:

> “Very smart owl you’ve got there,” chuckled Tom.  “Arrived about five
>   minutes after you did. If there’s  anything you need, Mr. Potter,
>   don’t hesitate to ask.”

On the other hand, there are times when it takes Hedwig very long to deliver mail, especially to/from Sirius. When waiting for Sirius's reply to the letter about Harry's scar pain, we find the following:

> “But we don’t know where Sirius is ... he could be in  Africa or
>   somewhere, couldn’t he?” said Hermione  reasonably. “Hedwig’s not
>   going to manage that  journey in a few days.”

This indicates that it is unreasonable to expect Hedwig to be able to fly to Africa in a few days. A few days later we find:

> “It’s been over a week,” Harry said, looking at  Hedwig’s deserted
>   perch. “Ron, you don’t reckon  Sirius has been caught, do you?”

This already implies that it is kind of expected for Hedwig to be able to fly both ways (to Africa, or even further) in about a week.

Hedwig didn't actually return for another four days after that, on Thursday night<sup>1</sup> while they were doing their Divination homework:

> “Hedwig!” he shouted, and he launched himself out of  his chair and
>   across the room to pull open the  window.

When Harry does get Sirius's reply he sends a letter right back. At this point Sirius is already on his way to the Hogwarts area, so we would expect Hedwig's journeys to be shorter. Yet Harry doesn't receive Sirius's next response until October 30, which is about a month and a half later:

> When they went down to breakfast on the morning of  the thirtieth of
>   October, they found that the Great  Hall had been decorated overnight.

There is no particular reason to think that Sirius took an especially long time to write the letter; in fact, the letter appears to be just a quick reply:

> Nice try, Harry.
>
> I’m back in the country and well hidden. I want you to  keep me posted
>   on everything that’s going on at  Hog warts. Don’t use Hedwig, keep
>   changing owls, and  don’t worry about me, just watch out for yourself.
>   Don’t  forget what I said about your scar.
>
> Sirius

Harry sends another letter to Sirius after his nighttime adventure with the egg, and it again takes a month for him to get Sirius's reply. This can be derived as follows: Harry goes to Hogsmeade halfway through January:

> There was a Hogsmeade visit halfway through  January. Hermione was
>   very surprised that Harry  was going to go.

After running into Rita Skeeter in Hogsmeade they go visit Hagrid. While there Dumbledore says:

> “I refuse to accept your  resignation, Hagrid, and I expect you back
>   at work on  Monday,” he said. “You will join me for breakfast at 
>   eight-thirty in the Great Hall. No excuses. Good  afternoon to you
>   all.”

After visiting Hagrid, Harry decides that it is time to take Cedric's advice:

> Lying to Hagrid wasn’t quite like lying to anyone else.  Harry went
>   back to the castle later that afternoon  with Ron and Hermione, unable
>   to banish the image  of the happy expression on Hagrid’s whiskery face
>   as  he had imagined Harry winning the tournament. The 
>   incomprehensible egg weighed more heavily than ever  on Harry’s
>   conscience that evening, and by the time  he had got into bed, he had
>   made up his mind — it  was time to shelve his pride and see if
>   Cedric’s hint  was worth anything.

We are then told when Harry went on his excursion:

> On Thursday night, Harry sneaked up to bed, put on  the cloak, crept
>   back downstairs, and, just as he had  done on the night when Hagrid
>   had shown him the  dragons, waited for the portrait hole to open.

Thus, this occurred almost a week after the Hogsmeade visit which was halfway through January. The next day, which would be Friday, Harry told Ron and Hermione about the previous night's adventure:

> Harry had been  recounting his adventures of the previous night in 
>   whispered installments for the last half hour.

Then we are told that Harry sent an owl to Sirius that night:

> Obedient to Sirius’s wish of hearing about anything  odd at Hogwarts,
>   Harry sent him a letter by brown  owl that night, explaining all about
>   Mr. Crouch  breaking into Snape’s office, and Moody and Snape’s 
>   conversation.

This means that Harry sent the owl on Friday night, one week after "halfway through January". So we're looking at somewhere around the 21st of January. Sirius's reply arrives on February 22nd:

> Just as it had before he faced the Horntail, time was  slipping away
>   as though somebody had bewitched the  clocks to go extra-fast. There
>   was a week to go before  February the twenty-fourth (there was still
>   time) ...  there were five days to go (he was bound to find  something
>   soon) ... three days to go (please let me find  something . . .
>   please) . . .
>
> With two days left, Harry started to go off food again.  The only good
>   thing about breakfast on Monday was  the return of the brown owl he
>   had sent to Sirius. He  pulled off the parchment, unrolled it, and saw
>   the  shortest letter Sirius had ever written to him.

Thus, it took a month for the owl to get to Sirius and back. Again, while it is possible that Sirius just waited a few weeks to write his reply, there is no particular reason why he would not write back as soon as possible, especially considering that his reply was to ask them when they would next be in Hogsmeade (if he delays replying he might miss the date).

However, the next exchange takes much less time. Harry responds immediately (Monday, February 22nd as per above) noting that the next Hogsmeade visit is the weekend after next. That would make it Saturday March 6th (assuming it was not a leap year – the actual year 1995 was not, but the days of the week in the book do not match the actual year of 1995, so who knows). Sirius's reply comes one day before that:

> The brown owl that Harry had sent to Sirius  with the dates of the
>   Hogsmeade weekend turned up  at breakfast on Friday morning with half
>   its feathers  sticking up the wrong way;

Thus, this exchange took only half as long as the previous one (February 22nd – March 5th).

After Visiting Sirius in Hogsmeade Harry sent a letter to Percy, and he didn't get the response for well over a month. This can be derived as follows: The Hogsmeade visit was on Saturday March 6th, and they sent the letter to Percy the next day:

> Harry, Ron, and Hermione went up to the Owlery  after breakfast on
>   Sunday to send a letter to Percy,  asking, as Sirius had suggested,
>   whether he had seen  Mr. Crouch lately.

Percy's reply didn't come until sometime in mid-April:

> Hedwig didn’t return until the end of the Easter  holidays.

Here it is more believable that Percy would have delayed responding, but it still took well over a month. On the other hand, the very day after sending Hedwig to Percy we find:

> When the post owls arrived, Hermione looked up  eagerly; she seemed to
>   be expecting something.
>
> “Percy won’t’ve had time to answer yet,” said Ron. “We  only sent
>   Hedwig yesterday.”

This indicates that it is pretty obvious that Hedwig can't make it to the Burrow and back in one day, but on the other hand, it is not so far out of the realm of possibility that Ron would never even suspect that Hermione thought that Percy's reply could have arrived.

After the incident with Mr. Crouch, Harry has another exchange with Sirius, but this time it only takes one day:

> Sirius sent their owl back the very next morning.

Clearly, it is possible for an owl to get to the mountain cave by Hogsmeade and back within one day (which is eminently reasonable, as Hogsmeade is within walking distance of Hogwarts).

In short, from the above few examples there already seems to be contradictory information about how long it takes Hedwig (and other owls) to travel. This is likely because JK Rowling did not put that much thought into making sure that all the owl journeys were consistent. Alternatively, the long waits for responses from Sirius is a plot device, and the author didn't care that it doesn't match how long the journeys should actually take.

---

### Notes

1. There is actually an inconsistency here. The "it's been over a week" comment occurred on Sunday:

> “It’s been an absolute uproar,” Percy told them  importantly the
>   Sunday evening before they were due  to return to Hogwarts.

The Hogwarts Express leaves the next day, which is Monday:

> There was a definite end-of-the-holidays gloom in the  air when Harry
>   awoke next morning. Heavy rain was  still splattering against the
>   window as he got dressed  in jeans and a sweatshirt; they would change
>   into  their school robes on the Hogwarts Express.

The first day of classes would then be Tuesday. Fred and George discuss their experience in Moody's class that evening at dinner:

> No sooner  had she gone than her seat was taken by Fred  Weasley.
>
> “Moody!” he said. “How cool is he?”
>
> “Beyond cool,” said George, sitting down opposite  Fred.
>
> “Supercool,” said the twins’ best friend, Lee Jordan,  sliding into
>   the seat beside George. “We had him this  afternoon,” he told Harry
>   and Ron.

We then find out that Harry doesn't have Moody until Thursday, which should be two days later:

> Ron dived into his bag for his schedule. “We haven’t got him till
>   Thursday!” he said in a  disappointed voice.

Yet their first class seems to have not occurred two days later on Thursday:

> The next two days passed without great incident, unless you counted
>   Neville melting his sixth cauldron  in Potions.

Yet when they do have the class the next day (which should be Friday) it is still Thursday:

> The Gryffindor fourth years were looking forward to 
>       Moody’s first lesson so much that they arrived early 
>       on Thursday lunchtime and queued up outside his 
>       classroom before the bell had even rung.

Thus, when Hedwig returned while they were doing their Divination homework the night of the day when they had Moody's first class, it should have been Friday five days later but according to the book it is Thursday (and thus only four days later).

Comment: I don’t think the correspondence with Sirius provides very good evidence that the evidence is “contradictory” as you say. There are dozens of reasons why Sirius may not rely immediately, or may intentionally make it seem to take longer to reply. Regardless if the letters he returns are short, you’ve made a rather big assumption on Sirius’ reply speed when no such evidence exists. As the youth of today might say “maybe he just left Harry on read.”

Comment: @Edlothiad Plus with Sirius travelling - probably mostly in dog form - Hedwig might have trouble finding him until he turns human again...

Comment: Just a note: 1 September when the Hogwarts train leaves is always a Sunday, and classes always start the following day, on a Monday. The Percy quote must be a mistake by Rowling; it should have read ‘Saturday’ for the rest of the calendar to make sense.

Comment: 1 September is always a Sunday? Do the magicals have a different calendar?

Answer (score 0):

At the start of *Prisoner of Azkaban*, Harry sends Hedwig off with a note for Ron, with instructions to keep herself away until Aunt Marge is gone. Aunt Marge stays for a week, and Hedwig reappears (presumably having delivered the note) the evening before Aunt Marge is due to depart, at the Leaky Cauldron where Harry has ended up.

Ron is at this point in *Egypt*. Ron's letter to Harry, which arrives on 31 July, says:

> It's brilliant here in Egypt. … We'll be back about a week before term starts…
>
> (PoA, page 13, 1st paperback edition, 1999)

(Term starts at the beginning of September, so 'a week before' will be around 23 August.)

Google Maps says the distance from Surrey to Egypt is 2350 miles. To get there and back in a week, Hedwig will have had to fly at a steady 28mph all week with no stops for rest (or faster with rests). In incredible heat.

According to [Environment Alaska](http://environmentalaska.us/snowy-owl.html), 30mph is towards the top end of flight speed for a snowy owl (they reach 50mph only when catching prey). [Birds of North America](https://birdsna.org/Species-Account/bna/species/snoowl1/distribution) says that during migrations snowy owls can cover 'hundreds of kilometers in a few days'. This trip is pushing it though, even for a snowy owl. Perhaps she stowed away on a plane? She is a very clever bird.

Comment: "Ron is at this point in _Egypt_": Do you have a quote to back this up that you can [edit] in? And "they reach 50mph only when catching prey" would mean they should easily be able to do 50mph without holding prey. Also of note is: _magic!_

Comment: A few hundred feet up, above the scorching sands, it's actually quite chilly